# incomprehensible logic preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have string:

```
$string = "1\n2\n3\n4\n\n\n";
```

And pattern:

```
$pattern = '/\s*$/';
// \s* - any spaces
// $   - end of string
```

Why when I call:

```
preg_replace($pattern, "\n5", $string);
```

Output is:

```
"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n5"
```

What is wrong with my pattern and how to change it, that the result will be:

```
"1\n2\n3\n4\n5"
```

Comment: seems to work fine? https://3v4l.org/g85VI

Comment: @mario, assert end of subject or before a terminating newline (or end of line, in multiline mode) [hph.net](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php)

Comment: If you know `$` means *end of string*, then I'm unsure why you expect the replace to add two `5`s at all. There's only *one* end of string that could be replaced. Please double check your example.

Comment: @deceze, Retterdesdialogs spoiled my original text

Comment: Alright - `\s*$` can match twice. Once for any number of spaces `\s*` before the end, and once more for the replaced line end `$` without any `\s*` spaces before.

Comment: @mario, why? It's monolithic expression, not /\s*|$/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` can match both the impending linebreak, as well as the end of a string.

Your main issue in this case however is `\s*` matching *zero* or more whitespace characters.

- For instance `\n\n␄` is matched and replaced first by `\s*$`
- As well as the `5\n␄` after the first replacement.

  - The `\s*$` gets treated as `$` simply.
  - And the new end of text ␄ still matches `$`.
  - It's not like `$` by itself always matches twice, but the combination of `\s*$` can.

The simplest fix is not to match for zero spaces, but make it only eat up existing whitespace:

```
/\s+$/
```

That's sufficient in your case, as you only care about the end of the string and cleaning out excess linebreaks anyway.